# flex - align last item to right

Tags: css, flexbox

1. How can I stretch the last item to the right, and  align  the filter icon to right end of the page?

   the grey background need to stretch to right
2. How can I center align the icons vertically in `flex`?

   `align-items:center;` causing the height of the `li` to collapse.

```css
body{
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ilgJJ1Q.gif);
  margin: 0;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
}
li{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 80px;
}
li:last-child{
  background: rgba(38, 46, 54, .6);
}
.c2{ background: #a15796; }
.c3{ background: #b48c4d; }
.c4{ background: #3a7d7d; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SRVh4os.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rBM2CYr.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9dFFuH5.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7bQ73kd.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yJ4vKBG.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/79pybrh9/

the actual page has text also with the icon

[image]

Comment: So you want `c1` to fill all the space to right?

Comment: need to extend  last one with  grey bg to right.

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have fixed height on `ul` you can use `line-height` for vertical align. Also you just have to add `flex: 1` to  `li:last-child` to take remaining  space.

---

Instad of `line-height` you can also use `display: flex` on each `li` and then center its content with `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/233/)

```css
body{
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/ilgJJ1Q.gif);
  margin: 0;
}
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
}
li{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
li:last-child{
  background: rgba(38, 46, 54, .6);
  flex: 1;
}
.c2{ background: #a15796; }
.c3{ background: #b48c4d; }
.c4{ background: #3a7d7d; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SRVh4os.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rBM2CYr.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9dFFuH5.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7bQ73kd.png" alt=""></li>
  <li class="c1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yJ4vKBG.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is there any other way other that `line-height` ? I need to add text to the right of  the icon later, which can be one line or two lines.

Comment: Yes there is, you can use `flex` on each `li` like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/233/

Comment: I have added text with the image, and also styled the `:after`.. [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/Lg0wyt9u/234/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/Lg0wyt9u/234/) .. Can you please look into it and guide me, if it is possible to align the `:after` below the text.. screenshot added in the question